# Cloud instance start time comparison

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Is anyone keeping track of the performance of instance start times from the various cloud providers (AWS, Azure, GCP etc.)?

Obviously this will depend on a lot of factors e.g. instance type, instance availability, operating system, definition of 'availability' etc. so a matrix and quartiles would be awesome (e.g. 98% of m1-small's running amazon linux in AWS in eu-west-1 are available in 34 seconds).

The reason I'm asking: I have a workload that happens intermittently but when it's needed, latency (i.e. start up time) is important. For cost reasons I'd prefer if the instance(s) aren't running when not used.

Unfortunately lambda's / web functions etc. won't work for me (although I'll be using them to start the instance(s)).

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing useful operationally. The most rigorous cross cloud study I found was done in 2012 at the University of Virginia. [A Performance Study on the VM Startup Time in the Cloud](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~anshul/courses/cse591_s16/vmsetuptime.pdf) ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1109/CLOUD.2012.103))  A long time ago, before GCP existed as an IaaS offering and when Azure was branded Windows Azure!

Anecdotal blogs from a single provider are more common than multi cloud. Again, already out of date, no one maintains this continuously that I know of. But sometimes you can find a bunch of data points for example: [Understanding and Profiling GCE cold-boot time](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-and-profiling-gce-cold-boot-time-32c209fe86ab)

Do your own timing of your instance types with your boot image in your regions of your clouds. Probably will be one or two minutes to ssh, plus or minus some seconds.

Increasing capacity faster than about 120 seconds will require booting instances a little before you need them. Maybe automatically via an instance scale group. That's the price of low latency.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, 2 minutes is painful but should be ok for latency. It feels like the kind of stat that would be interesting to track (e.g. for time to do a rolling upgrade). I suspect people are but just not publishing it.

Comment: 120 seconds is just a guess, measure it. Instance boot time is less interesting with a sufficiently large and automated fleet, where scale and upgrade changes happen constantly. If there always is enough capacity to serve the next request, response time rarely  suffers during capacity scaling.